# PHP OOP access of protected members

Tags: php, oop

Example code

```
class Example {

    protected $data = 'data ';

    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function mergeWith(Example $e) {
        $this->data .= $e->data;
    }

}

$e1 = new Example();
$e2 = new Example();

$e1->mergeWith($e2);
```

Result is

```
Example Object
(
    [data:protected] => data data 
)
```

My question is - why am I able to access the protected/private properties of an object from outside the object? It is the same class but it is a different instance, shouldn't that count as an outside call? What is the idea behind this?

Comment: The visibility is defined in terms of class hierarchy, not instances. So `protected`s are accessed by all instances of the same hierarchy. So any object that is `instaceof Example` can access it. That works the same way in pretty much every other (?) programming language that implements similar object model.

Comment: @zerkms I don't know why I always thought protected/private members could only be accessed by the instance they belong to. Kind of made more sense to me I guess..

Comment: @zerkms you should post that as an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visibility is defined in terms of class hierarchy, not instances. So `protected`s are accessed by all instances of the same hierarchy. So any object that is `instaceof Example` can access it.

That works the same way in pretty much every other (?) programming language that implements similar object model. Just out of the top of my head: C++ (with some exceptions, but in general it's still applicable here), C#, Java.